# Console Role Playing Game

Tags: code-challenge, game

Below are a basic set of requirements.

---

The following commands (for an interface to the game):

```
attack <target>, <move>
goto <place>
buy <item>
enum <
    targets,
    moves,
    places,
    items,
    stats
>
```

---

The following player stats:

- HP
- MP/SP (Mana/Stamina)
- XP
- Level
- Gold
- Items

---

### Scoring

(Thanks to @Casey for this idea.)

For each feature implemented, you gain 1 point. The post with the greatest number of points becomes the winner. In the event of a tie, the post with the highest number of votes becomes the winner. (In the event of a tie for *that*, the master of the dimensions [me] chooses.)

---

BONUS: Make it fun! Add something special.

Comment: Please see http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/305/what-makes-winning-criteria-objective

Comment: @Juan It'll be the highest voted game. It's like Wolfenstein 3D vs Halo Reach. Guess which one'll be highest voted?

Comment: *"It's preferable to post the binaries"* No, it's not. I'm willing to consider re-opening if we get something resembling an objective winning condition.

Comment: @dmckee Is that a bit better? What would you suggest?

Comment: Idea: Assign features points, submissions get points based on # of features they implement. In the event of a tie, the checkmark goes to the highest scoring post (i.e., of those who are tied) with the most upvotes.

Comment: @Casey If you could edit for me (I don't get exactly what you mean), that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: @muntoo Well its your question, so I don't want to change it. But here is an explanation of what I mean. Give each feature a point value. For example  the 'attack' command/system could be worth 5 points, while the movement feature could be 1 point. That way people can implement whatever they want (though some features will build on eachother) and they are scored according to how many features they implement.

Comment: @muntoo That's a step in the right direction, but I think you should explicitly list features. Not just the features you have, but as many as you can think of. Otherwise what counts as a feature is subjective. For example, if I implement multiple types of NPCs is that a feature per NPC or does that fall under the 'attack' feature?